# Embedding video in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have below code to embed video. but it is not working.
Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://vimeo.com/63534746"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Embed code for that specific video, found when you click the share button is: `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/63534746?color=ffffff" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/63534746">Light Bikes</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/ericcorriel">Eric Corriel</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p> `

Comment: add height and  with to your iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get back in the console is `Refused to display 'https://vimeo.com/63534746' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` so Vimeo is blocking you from doing what you are trying to do.

There are three possible values for X-Frame-Options:

**DENY** - The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site  attempting to do so.

**SAMEORIGIN** - The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

**ALLOW-FROM uri** - The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.

Instead of embedding that whole page, you can use the embed code provided by Vimeo (found by clicking the 'Share' button).

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/63534746?color=ffffff" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>
    <a href="https://vimeo.com/63534746">Light Bikes</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/ericcorriel">Eric Corriel</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The link you used leads to the video's page, not to the video "embedding" page. You can use the "share" feature of the site to get the right `iframe` code:

[image]